# Why is browser detecting top as bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load more images when user hits the bottom of page. I found numerous questions explaining how to do that but I always get top not buttom.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        alert('bottom');
    }
});
```

This snippet should alert when bottom is reached but instead it alerts when top is reached. This happens on Chrome and Safari. Can not understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this `if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) < 1)`

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) < 1) {
      console.log('at bottom')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
  Loooong content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: @KārlisJanisels I use Chrome and it works perfect for me. Do you mean this snippet doesn't work? ... Which version do you use?

Comment: The one you provided in your answer. I have tried several different approaches that works in all other browsers but not in chrome

Comment: @KārlisJanisels Since I use Chrome, 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit), and it works for me, you must have missed something while copying my code. If you post what you use in a fiddle I'll have a look

Comment: Oh ok, I found my mistake - I do not have height property set for body. But I need that to stay in that way

Comment: @KārlisJanisels Was there something with my update that still doesn't work for you?

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not post how it all ended. I did not had <!DOCTYPE html>. That was the reason why Chrome detected document height as 0. The code wasnt the problem.

Comment: @KārlisJanisels Ok, great, though your posted script code doesn't work properly, my posted answer does, so an accept would be appreciated